# Где хранится Native Code?

Tags: android, java

Все мы знаем, что у Dalvik есть стек и куча. Там лежат обьекты, созданные во время исполнения Java кода. Обьекты лежат в Dalvik-heap.

А где хранятся нативные обьекты, которые были созданы с помощью вызова нативных функций.

Поясняю. Вызываем функцию из натива. Во время ее выполнения создаются обьекты и локальные переменные. Где они хранятся? Вряд ли всё это вертится внутри Dalvik.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dalvik - это, если можно так выразиться, "простой софт", который вертится в недрах операционной системы, ядро которой - Linux.

Нативные функции, написанные, например, на C++, не нуждаются в виртуализированном окружении, каковым является Dalvik.
Соответственно то, что используется вне этого самого "простого софта" (виртуальной машины), работает и хранит свои данные за ее пределами, т.е. в целевой ОС.

Чтобы понять, на каком именно уровне ("сэндвича OS Android") исполняется нативный код, достаточно будет просто взглянуть на схему устройства этой OS: **[HAL](https://www.google.ru/search?q=android+hardware+abstraction+layer&newwindow=1&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=52f-U7ieD-z34QSyv4CICw&ved=0CB4QsAQ&biw=1366&bih=643)**

А вообще, конечно, вопрос хороший, с философской точки зрения.